# Handelbars variables via Handlebars.registerPartial

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, partials

I have a Handelbars app that loads data from javascript and partials for the templates. To get the templates to work I use the following in the Javascript:

```
var data = require('partials/data.js');
Handlebars.registerPartial('data', data);
```

Then in my partial I am able to do:

`{{> data }}`

I have a Handelbars variable I can use in my main template but I want to pass it down to the partial. With my other partials that don't register via the Javascript this is possible. I am assuming I need to pass this variable down like I do the templates?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [handlebars documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-parameters), you should be able to simply pass the variable down as a parameter, like so:

```
{{> data parameter=variable }}
```